# Using PowerShell's New-WebServiceProxy to access a net.tcp endpoint

Tags: wcf, web-services, powershell

I am trying to access a net.tcp endpoint from powershell.
I would like to use [New-WebServiceProxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315258.aspx) for that purpose, however I am not sure if it can be done.
Right now I get a

```
    
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
```

when pointing it at the wsdl (which I have heavly hand written, so it could be that...)

Comment: Have checked google :http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=New-WebServiceProxy+net.tcp Am I the only person trying to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply cannot do this. [New-WebServiceProxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315258.aspx) is not a WCF proxy, its a http soap proxy.

You could probably use a combination of [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133.aspx) and [Add-Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315241.aspx) to generate the proxy on the fly on machines that have svcutil.exe installed.

A more complex example [in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zelmalki/archive/2008/12/15/create-dynamic-wcf-clients-without-any-configuration-service-references.aspx) that you might be able to translate to powershell is available here.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you have been able to do this since December 22nd 2008. [Christian Glessner](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/) wrote a WCF Proxy generator.

The original blog post in which he described it is [here](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2008/12/call-wcf-services-with-powershell.html). He also posted the script in [this PoshCode.org post](http://poshcode.org/747).

I updated the code to [Powershell v2](https://github.com/justaprogrammer/PowerShellWCF/). I'd suggest using that version. I talk about my version on [this blog post](http://www.justaprogrammer.net/2012/02/11/using-powershell-to-call-a-wcf-service/).

If you use that code, dotsource it from another script, don't include it inline. Here is an example using my version of the code:

```
# My example WCF service:
# https://github.com/justaprogrammer/EchoService
. .\wcf.ps1

$wsdlImporter = Get-WsdlImporter 'http://localhost.fiddler:14232/EchoService.svc/mex'
Get-WsdlImporter 'http://localhost.fiddler:14232/EchoService.svc' -HttpGet
Get-WsdlImporter 'http://localhost.fiddler:14232/EchoService.svc?wsdl' -HttpGet 

$proxyType = Get-WcfProxyType $wsdlImporter

$endpoints = $wsdlImporter.ImportAllEndpoints();
$proxy = New-Object $proxyType($endpoints[0].Binding, $endpoints[0].Address);
$proxy = Get-WcfProxy 'http://localhost.fiddler:14232/EchoService.svc/mex'
$proxy.Echo("Justin Dearing");

Get-Help Get-WsdlImporter
Get-Help Get-WcfProxyType
Get-Help Get-WcfProxy
```